# How can I check what type of data a java map contains?

Tags: java, dictionary

I've got a generic map in some java code that can contain, for a specific field, either a String or an Array, but I'm pretty new to Java and am not quite sure how to distinguish between the two.

My current idea is to write a class with an overloaded method that will do different things with the two data types, but what I'd *really* like to do is to use something like `typeof` from javascript to controll an if statement, rather than creating a whole new class.

Is there such a thing in Java? And is there a better way to do this? I'm getting the array out of code I have no control over, so changing the map isn't an option.

Comment: There is `instanceof`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your map contains objects. You can test the type of an object with `instanceof`.

For example:

```
 Object value = map.get( key );
 if ( value instanceof String ) {
     ...
 }
 else if ( value instanceof Object[] ) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't cover all arrays. Better: `value.getClass().isArray()`.

Comment: Right, Object[] is an *example*. If you're looking for *any* array, your code is best. If you're looking for a specific type of array, instanceof is sufficient.